# How to display only once echo command in a Bash loop

Tags: bash, loops, echo

My problem is pretty simple. I have :

```
a=$(echo "lol")

for i in {1..3}; 
do 
echo $a && echo $i ; 
done
```

I get :

```
lol
1
lol
2
lol
3
```

I would like to print only once the variable `a` at the beginning of the output , to get :

```
lol
1
2
3
```

Any idea?

Comment: Move `echo $a` before your loop?

Comment: I guess you have made a simplified example, otherwise why not just write `a=lol`?

Comment: Also bear in mind that maybe you can just write `printf '%d\n' {1..3}`  instead of your loop.

Comment: Maybe you can update your question to show us a more representative example of what you're trying to do? Or is it really just a case of moving the `echo` out of the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop at all

```sh
a=$(echo "lol") # Not sure why poster wrote this rater than a=lol

printf %s\\n "$a" {1..3}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="lol"$'\n'      # append newline

for i in {1..3}
do
  echo -e "$a$i"  # -e: enable interpretation of escape sequences
  unset a
done
```

Or replace in your question

```
echo $a && echo $i ;
```

with

```
[[ "$i" == "1" ]] && echo "$a"
echo "$i"
```

See: `help echo` and `help unset`

Answer (score 0):

Move the echo outside of the for loop

```
a=$(echo "lol")

echo $a
for i in {1..3}; do 
    echo $i; 
done
```

or:

```
echo "lol"
for i in {1..3}; do 
    echo $i; 
done
```

[test run in shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbVZG.png)